# Saving webcam jpeg stream to multiple files with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, webcam, mjpeg, matroska

I'm trying to save a MJPEG stream from a logitech C920 webcam to multiple video files (matroska).

I've got this pipeline: (1 mkv file every 60s)

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,framerate=24/1 \
! matroskamux ! multifilesink next-file=max-duration max-file-duration=60000000000 location='test1-%02d.mkv'
```

It outputs several files, as expected, but the files have errors, so tools like avidemux can't play them back. mkvalidator reports these:

```
WRN080: Unknown element [FF] at 293 size 88
WRN080: Unknown element [FF] at 494 size 64
WRN080: Unknown element [7D][01] at 566 size w98603107602
WRN801: The segment has no SeekHead section
WRN0B8: Track #1 is defined but has no frame
```

BTW, saving to a single file using filesink produces an mkv file without errors.

Is there a way to save multiple mkv files properly?
Any other container is also OK, but I cannot transcode (need low CPU load) and I cannot use raw (need HD with high fps).

I'm using GStreamer 1.8.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Thanks.

Update:
Following the advice below, I tried with splitmuxsink:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video1 \
! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,framerate=24/1 \
! splitmuxsink muxer=matroskamux location='test1-%02d.mkv' \
max-size-time=10000000000
```

But it doesn't work: The file is never split and keeps growing in size.

Comment: Try this:gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,framerate=24/1 ! jpegparse ! splitmuxsink muxer=matroskamux location='test1-%02d.mkv' max-size-time=10000000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got success with an upgraded GStreamer (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version
GStreamer Core Library version 1.14.1
```

Here is a pipeline with an AVI container, where a new file is generated every ten seconds:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video1 \
! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,framerate=24/1 \
! splitmuxsink muxer=avimux location='test1-%02d.avi' max-size-time=10000000000
```

It also works with matroskamux.

Answer (score 0):

The following pipeline seems to work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src ! x264enc key-int-max=10 ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink muxer=matroskamux location='test1-%02d.mkv' max-size-time=60000000000
```

`multifilesink` doesn't know nothing about the container format, so you must use `splitmuxsink` to do the spliting.

Here is the quote from [multifilesink doc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-multifilesink.html#gst-plugins-good-plugins-multifilesink.description):

> It is not possible to use this element to create independently
>   playable mp4 files, use the splitmuxsink element for that instead.

Comment: Isn't `x264enc key-int-max=10` reencoding? I can't do that. Also, I want to record the original MJPEG video using a Matroska/MP4 container, not h.264.

Comment: Ah, you can remove x264enc if you just want to put your mjpeg stream in Matroska container.  I just put that for my webcam, which don't have mjpeg capability.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried without the `x264enc` element, but it doesn't work. I'll update the question with the issue.

Comment: @All Cant we specify at what frame rate the video files are to be dumped? like is there any flag for framerate while dumping the stream to files